# Reasteasy desn't found the jettison jaxb rpovider

Tags: json, maven, jaxb, resteasy

I am getting:

```
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.JAXBMarshalException: Could not find JAXBContextFinder for media type: application/json
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.findJAXBContext(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:50)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.getMarshaller(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:127)
```

on the client side... i have the following pom.xml where you can see jettison jaxb provider is on as well as the jettison core jar:

```
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss</id>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>maven</id>
            <url>http://mvnrepository.com//maven2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>5.0</version>
   </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.34</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>5.1</version>
        </dependency>
           <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JAXB support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.scannotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>scannotation</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jettison-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
            <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

In the User DTO used on my client call i have the XmlRootElement annotation and the call is:

```
public UserDTO getUserData(String userName) {
    webTarget = client.target(BASE_URI).path("Login/GetUserData");
    Form form = new Form();
    form.param("userName", userName);

    Response requestResult;
    Entity<Form> entity;
    MediaType sent = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE;
    entity = Entity.entity(form, sent);
    MediaType [] accepted = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE};
    requestResult = webTarget.request(accepted)
            .post(entity);
    UserDTO result = (UserDTO)requestResult.getEntity();
    return result;
}
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

According to [resteasy 3.0.2 jettison example](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/tree/3.0.2/jaxrs/examples/jaxb-json) you don't need resteasy-jaxb-provider dependency. I think that's included in resteasy-jettison-provider.

See if removing resteasy-jaxb-provider dependency, and updating resteasy-jettison-provider version to 3.0.2 helps..